# In scala, How to call generalised copy function of a case class if it is declared in a family outer type?

Tags: scala, inner-classes, path-dependent-type, scala-2.13

This is a scala problem caused by path-dependent type: Considering that I have a family type:

```scala
trait Outer {
  
  case class Inner(v: Int) {

    val outer = Outer.this
  }
}
```

If I want to call `Outer#Inner.copy()` when the instance of `Outer` is unknown:

```scala
def cp(src: Outer#Inner) = {
  src.copy()
}
```

I will run into a compilation error. as the type signature of src.copy() is attached to its outer instance.

One way to bypass this is to extract the outer instance manually:

```scala
def cp(src: Outer#Inner) = {
  val o = src.outer
  val _src = src.asInstanceOf[o.Inner]

  _src.copy()
}
```

This can compiler successfully, but the `asInstanceOf[]` is clearly a hacking artefact and should be removed.

In idiomatic scala, what's the best way to achieve the same goal, while let the scala compiler automatically infer the existence of `outer`, and generate the correct type signature without blind type casting?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Outer#Inner`, you need to constrain the `Outer` type using a type parameter. Try

```
def cp[O <: Outer](src: O#Inner): O#Inner = src.copy()
```

This will let you maintain `O#Inner`, which refers to one specific type, as opposed to `Outer#Inner`.

See it in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XiUjo7djRROPdOIpImFK9Q).

Comment: strange, it doesn't work for me. Just got type mismatch;
 found   : (some other)_1.type(in method cp)#universe.Type where type (some other)_1.type(in method cp) <: R with Singleton
 required: _1.type(in method cp)#universe.Type where type _1.type(in method cp) <: R with Singleton

Comment: Sorry different scenario, published to Part2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132770/in-scala-2-13-why-implicit-sometimes-can-be-summoned-directly-but-not-indirect. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Also, your Scastie has a message: reflective access of structural type member value inner should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.reflectiveCalls visible.
----
Obviously it means the code is not efficient. So probably not the ideal answer

Comment: @tribbloid I don't know why you're getting a type mismatch, let me work on that. As for the warning, it's just because I used a structural type instead of a class extending Outer. That has nothing to do with the method `cp`, just the other object I'm using, so you don't need to worry about its efficiency.

Comment: The mismatch was for a different scenario, sorry for the confusion