# In scala, How to call generalised copy function of a case class if it is declared in a family outer type? - Part 2

Tags: scala, inner-classes, path-dependent-type, scala-2.13

This is a follow up question of Part1:

[In scala, How to call generalised copy function of a case class if it is declared in a family outer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67050091/in-scala-how-to-call-generalised-copy-function-of-a-case-class-if-it-is-declare)

In Part 2, the definition of the family class become slightly more complex:

```
trait OuterSpike {

  class Thing

  case class Inner(v: Thing) {

    //    val outer = self
  }
}

object OuterSpike {

  {

    def cp(src: OuterSpike#Inner): OuterSpike#Inner = {
      src.copy()
    }

    def cp2[O <: OuterSpike](src: O#Inner): O#Inner = src.copy()

    val outer = new OuterSpike {
      val inner = this.Inner(new Thing)
    }
    cp(outer.inner)
  }
}
```

So the old trick no longer works, the above compiles with the following error:

```
[Error] /home/peng/git/shapesafe/graph-commons/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/graph/commons/util/reflect/format/OuterSpike.scala:18: type mismatch;
 found   : com.tribbloids.graph.commons.util.reflect.format.OuterSpike#Thing
 required: _1.Thing where val _1: com.tribbloids.graph.commons.util.reflect.format.OuterSpike
[Error] /home/peng/git/shapesafe/graph-commons/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/graph/commons/util/reflect/format/OuterSpike.scala:21: type mismatch;
 found   : O#Thing
 required: _1.Thing where val _1: O
two errors found
```

How to make it compile in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are refining `OuterSpike` with `val inner` which is dependent on `outer` instance

```
val outer = new OuterSpike {
  val inner = this.Inner(new Thing)
}
```

so try with dependent types instead of type projection

```
def cp(outer: OuterSpike)(src: outer.Inner): outer.Inner = {
  src.copy()
}
cp(outer)(outer.inner)
```

Comment: Sometimes outer is not available. Imagine outer being defined out of the scope

Comment: @tribbloid Would `src` not have a reference to `outer`? (you had that in the previous version of your code, and I see a commented out field in the current question)

Comment: it is possible, but now you'll have to use an unsafe cast to coerce src again

Answer (score 0):

Define a no-arg `cp` on the `Inner` perhaps?

```
trait OuterSpike { 
  class Thing
  case class Inner(v: Thing) {
     def cp() = copy()
  }
}

object OuterSpike {
    def cp[O <: OuterSpike](src: O#Inner) = src.cp()
    val outer = new OuterSpike {
      val inner = this.Inner(new Thing)
    }
    cp(outer.inner)
}
```

Alternatively, you can relax the definition of `Inner` a little bit:

```
case class Inner(v: OuterSpike#Thing)
```

If you define it like this, then `def cp[O <: OuterSpike](src: O#Inner) = src.copy()` works.

Comment: Works, but my question focus on solving it within scala's type system

Comment: @tribbloid I see ... And old, good XY-problem :) Good luck!

Comment: @tribbloid I added another option to the answer ... not sure if you consider that "within" or "outside" the type system :)

Comment: ok I'm not allowed to change the definition of OuterSpike, it is not my code. In reality the OuterSpike is actually scala reflection universe, yuge cluster of family polymorphism